# flash - draw box in video and track object

Tags: flash, video

first the issue at hand:
user uploads a video, then they need to draw a box around an object in the video, then have that object tracked as video plays. Basically the end result needs to be a "clickable image map" of the video.

researched and researched and have come up with a few possiblities but they are all built for webcams and not sure which of them is the best as I'm not the best as3 programmer.

was wondering if anybody has any particular suggestions or recommendations?

here's the results of my search so far...

faceit:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxY2M0kNqvs

openCV in flash:
http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000687.php

webcam tracking - could be tweeked to track video ?
http://blog.soulwire.co.uk/code/actionscript-3/webcam-motion-detection-tracking

not released yet:
http://blog.inspirit.ru/

thanks for your help